# Change resolution and nothing works now

Tags: display, resolution, cable

I changed in a game my resolution and monitor turned to black saying "change your resolution in 1900x1200", when restart pc it keeps saying the same thing from very start (i mean i can't see nothing not even bios boot nothing at all). I turned to mother's board onboard graphic card in order to make it to safe mode. When windows load and updated graphic cards drivers (this on board) BOOM the same message appeared. I restored pc in previous time. I made it again to safe mode (with onboard card), and deleted all graphic drivers, when i restarted pc .......... "change your resolution......". I change even HD with other OS (hopping to start) but the same problem.

What i tried, 
-change from Nvidia GTX 560 to onboard (this works until safe mode)
-replaced RAM
-changed HD
-Removed graphic drivers and reinstall for both cards (after install's restart , same problem arise)
-Recover windows in previous time

Now display two messages :

-with onboard graphic card = "change resolution to...."
-with 560 = "Check display cable"

These messages appears from very start meaning i can't do nothing (GTX 560). Only with on board i can make it throw safe mode where the resolution appears to be 800x600........ PLZ give a hand..... TY in advance

Comment: You have not provided which operatingsystem you are using. Because of this, I cannot look up what key combinations you need to press in order to change your resolution. My recommendation would be to figure out the keypresses using an alternative computer running the same version, then let the computer boot to windows, and use the key combinations to change the resolution to 1024x768.

Comment: Try an external monitor and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the monitor PHILIPS one 22' which i have. It saves the last resolution received from GPU, so a friend sent me a new GPU, which I put it in the slot and started pc, got in windows and pressed "shut down"... after that i put in my GPU (GTX 560) and monitor saw it as a new one and started normally (i had drivers installed).